# How to deploy an exe with a .bat that does some checks.

Tags: group-policy

I have to run a .exe that uninstall a specific software on all our clients. But i have to uninstall only a specific release of it. I will create a .bat that does this check for me. Can i deploy it like that with a GPO? I will have to thell the GPO to load both the .exe and the .bat. Will it work? Sorry I am a trainee without much experience in GPOs.

Thank you:)

Comment: You can use group policy to create startup and shutdown scripts and also scheduled tasks. When do you want this uninstaller to run?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which software this is, the best I can do is to offer you some places to look for more info.

Some software has command line switches that can show you the version of the software installed (usually -v) and that could be used in your Batch file logic to determine whether the right version is installed.

Some software puts a version marking in the registry somewhere. You could check for that to determine the installed version.

And finally, it may not be that intrusive to simply have GPO "Update" the .exe file itself, which would make sure that all machines where this policy is applied would have the same version.

Comment: We upgraded from LANDesk to Ivanti on a new server with another name and ip. We have migrated the data bank. The agents on the data bank will be upgraded with a task on the server. Clients that are offline for a long time are no more in the data bank. I need to be sure that if they will be online they will receive the new agent. I think i could just uninstall the old agent with a gpo (unfortunately the uninstaller will also uninstall any other version of LANDesk and Ivanti EM without a .bat) and then let the new server check for clients without any agent and push the new one. Better ideas?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to direct the old landesk clients at the new ivanti server.  Use DNS CNAME or A Record to point your LanDesk clients at the new ivanti server (Since you said it's now on another name and IP)   Once those old agents come online they will check in with ivanti and the agents can get updated with the task.

Comment: It sounds cool but I am not sure how to do this. I mean we will shut down the old server because of license expiring in about 30 days and if any old client will be online it won't be able to communicate with the new server because the agent will still try to reach the old server. I searched for cname and they are just the names that resolves a ip. Right? How do i apply what you said? Thank you anyway :)